# How to display answer in a statement

Tags: ruby

I have to write a code to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit. In the end, I need it to display the answer in a statement. I'm trying to get it to display the number entered by the user is the answer Fahrenheit.

> Example the user input 104 so the statement should read: 104 celsius
>   is 219 Fahrenheit.

I have tried many different ways to get it to work but as close as I can get is it showing 219 Fahrenheit without the beginning of the sentence.

Here is my code:

When I tried using the `#{degrees}` I get an error. I tried using the + to connect them into one sentence and got an error. What you see below is all that has worked.

```
def c_to_f
  puts "Enter degrees Celsius"
  degrees = gets
  (degrees.to_i * 9/5) + 32
end

puts c_to_f

puts "Fahrenheit."
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! if you are getting some error, showing us the error makes it easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: "I get an error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? What is the error message? What does it say? What line does it occur on? What method does it occur in? Please, show the relevant portion of the stack trace as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
def c_to_f 
  puts "Enter degrees Celsius" 
  degrees = gets 
  fh = (degrees.to_i * 9/5) + 32 
  puts "#{fh} Fahrenheit."
end

# call the function
c_to_f
```

Comment: I tried it and it just printed the same number I typed in. It did not do the calculation. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks, it worked. I really appreciate the help. I'm in a course just learning ruby so I don't know all the tricks yet. :)

Comment: If you are `puts`ing inside the method, u do not need to `puts` the return of the method itself.

Answer (score 4):

> How to display answer in a statement

Assuming you have two variables with integer values:

```
celsius = 104
fahrenheit = 219
```

There are several options to turn these into the sentence *"104 celsius is 219 Fahrenheit."*

You could print each part separately using [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-print) which doesn't add a newline:

```
print celsius
print ' Celsius is '
print fahrenheit
print ' Fahrenheit.'
puts  # <- this adds a newline
```

Or you could print all parts with a single `print` call:

```
print celsius, ' Celsius is ', fahrenheit, ' Fahrenheit.'
puts
```

You could also build the sentence by concatenating strings using [`+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-2B) as you already tried. But in order to work, each part has to be a string so the numbers need to be converted via [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-to_s):

```
puts celsius.to_s + ' Celsius is ' + fahrenheit.to_s + ' Fahrenheit.'
```

A more idiomatic way is to *interpolate* the values into a string using `#{...}`: (you have to use double quotes)

```
puts "#{celsius} Celsius is #{fahrenheit} Fahrenheit."
```

And finally there is [`format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-format) which builds a string from a template using placeholders: (`%d` = decimal)

```
puts format('%d Celsius is %d Fahrenheit.', celsius, fahrenheit)
```

---

Apart from the sentence, I've noticed that your `c_to_f` method currently does more than just converting Celsius to Fahrenheit:

```
def c_to_f
  puts "Enter degrees Celsius"  # <- printing
  degrees = gets                # <- collecting input
  (degrees.to_i * 9/5) + 32     # <- string conversion and finally C to F
end
```

I'd write this as:

```
def c_to_f(degrees)
  degrees * 9 / 5 + 32
end
```

And move the output / input outside the method:

```
puts 'Enter degrees Celsius'
celcius = gets.to_i
fahrenheit = c_to_f(celsius)
```

This makes the method much more versatile, e.g. when used without user input:

```
puts 'Conversion table:'
(-30..100).step(10) do |c|
  puts format('%3d °C = %3d °F', c, c_to_f(c))
end
```

`%3d` means decimal value with a width of 3. Shorter numbers will be padded with spaces which results in a nicely aligned output:

```
Conversion table:
-30 °C = -22 °F
-20 °C =  -4 °F
-10 °C =  14 °F
  0 °C =  32 °F
 10 °C =  50 °F
 20 °C =  68 °F
 30 °C =  86 °F
 40 °C = 104 °F
 50 °C = 122 °F
 60 °C = 140 °F
 70 °C = 158 °F
 80 °C = 176 °F
 90 °C = 194 °F
100 °C = 212 °F
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to display both the input and the output values in the statement, you should probably `puts` inside the method.

```
def c_to_f
  puts "Enter degrees Celsius"
  c_degrees = gets.to_i
  f_degrees = (c_degrees * 9/5) + 32
  puts "#{c_degrees} celsius is #{f_degrees} in Fahrenheit"
end

c_to_f
```